# UWP (VB.Net) StreamSocketListener not firing connected event

Tags: vb.net, sockets, uwp, listener

I'm trying to setup a socket listener in a Universal Windows Platform App. The app will run on a Raspberry PI and listen for communications from an in-motion scale.

I've setup a StreamSocketListener in my mainVM file. I've got commands to start and stop it. I've followed the few guides online i can find, but it won't fire the event when the scale sends the data. I've tested with a listener app that I downloaded, so i can confirm that the messages are being sent and my computer is able to receive them (no firewall issues). (I also know that only one app can listen to a port, so this tester is off when testing my program.)

I'll get one hit on the handler function when it first starts the connection, but i never get anything again. No errors, just nothing happening.

Commands:

```
Public Property cmdStart As New Command(Async Sub() Await StartListener(), True)
Public Property cmdStop As New Command(Sub() StopListener(), True)
```

Command Subroutines:

```
Private Async Function StopListener() As Task
    If Connected Then
        Await _prePriceListener.CancelIOAsync()
        RemoveHandler _prePriceListener.ConnectionReceived, Nothing
        _prePriceListener.Dispose()
        Connected = False
    End If
End Function

Private Async Function StartListener() As Task
    If ValidateInput() Then
        Try
            _prePriceListener = New StreamSocketListener()
            _prePriceListener.Control.KeepAlive = False
            AddHandler _prePriceListener.ConnectionReceived, AddressOf HandlerReceived
            Await _prePriceListener.BindServiceNameAsync("6021")
            Connected = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Message = ex.Message
        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

Event Handler:

```
Private Async Function HandlerReceived(sender As StreamSocketListener, args As StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs) As Task
    Dim msgReceived As String = ""
    Dim inStream As Stream
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Try

        inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()
        reader = New StreamReader(inStream)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return
    End Try

    Try
        If reader IsNot Nothing Then
            msgReceived = Await reader.ReadLineAsync()
            HandlePrepriceRead(msgReceived)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return
    End Try
End Function
```

I've tried with _prePriceListener.Control.KeepAlive set to both true and false. When true, it hangs on msgReceived = Await reader.ReadLineAsync() in the handler. I suspect that is the issue, but every fix i've found made no difference. My only other suspicion is incorrect use of Async/Await but i can't find much information to either confirm or deny that. (I think i know what i'm doing with that, but i may be at that level of knowing just enough to be dangerous...)

Anyway, any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the scale is sending an EOL (\n or \r or \r\n) HEX 13 and or 10 ? I could see your code waiting for an something the scale is never sending. *FYI I'm not sure what kind of scale you are using or how quickly it talks or your application but if the scale is on continuous feed this probably isn't going to work very well for you as the scale and all the parts along the way will buffer things and the weight will be gone by the time you process this event (after a while atleast)

Comment: @Someonethatmatters That could very well be the problem. the testing utility doesn't print any new line (though that could be designed that way) and i remember the guy programming the scale asking if we needed an EOL in it. I'll look into that. As for the scale: it has photo-eyes. it begins weighting when the first one is passed and stops at the second. the scale performs a calculation and sends it to a set IP address (where my app will run).

Comment: @Someonethatmatters That was the issue. If you want to answer it i'll select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the scale is sending an EOL (\n or \r or \r\n) HEX 13 and or 10 ? I could see your code waiting for an something the scale is never sending. *FYI I'm not sure what kind of scale you are using or how quickly it talks or your application but if the scale is on continuous feed this probably isn't going to work very well for you as the scale and all the parts along the way will buffer things and the weight will be gone by the time you process this event (after a while atleast)